# C code, write integer without zeros and odds

Tags: c

I wrote a code that count how many zeros, odds and evens are in the numbers provided by the user.

How do I need to change this code, so that in result i have :

1. Numbers from user without odds (for example if user writes 1234 i need that program will write 24)
2. Numbers from user without zeros. (for example if user writes 1005 i need that program will write 15)

Thank you.

```
int sk,a=0,b=0,c=0;
printf ("Write number: ");
scanf("%d", &sk);

while (sk!=0){
    if (sk%10==0){
        a++;
    }
    else if (sk%2==0){
        b++;
    }
    else {
        c++;
    }
    sk=sk/10;
}
printf(" Zeros %d \n Evens %d \n Odss %d ",a , b, c);
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: Input printf ("Write number: ")  and output for example  printf(" Zeros %d \n Evens %d \n Odss %n \n Number without zeros %d \n Number without odds %d ",a , b, c, d, e);

Comment: @DžoNis No that is console output

Comment: I need this code only in console for my studies

Comment: I nedd that if user writes 123456 than without odds result should be 246. If user writes writes 102030 than result should be 123 its without zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help :)

```
int sk,a=0,b=0,c=0;

int cnt_a=1,cnt_b=1,cnt_c=1;

printf ("Write number : ");
scanf("%d", &sk);

while (sk != 0){
    if (sk%10 != 0){
        a = a + (sk%10 * cnt_a);
        cnt_a *= 10;
    }
    if (sk%2==0){
        b = b + (sk%10 * cnt_b);
        cnt_b *= 10;
    }
    else {
        c = c + (sk%10 * cnt_c);
        cnt_c *= 10;
    }
    sk = sk/10;
}
printf(" Without Zeros : %d \n Only Evens : %d \n Only Odds : %d ", a , b, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'printf' function, like above this, and you will receive your missing variables.

```
int sk,a=0,b=0,c=0;
printf ("Write number: ");
scanf("%d", &sk);

while (sk != 0) {
  if (sk%10 == 0){
    a++;
  }
  else if (sk%2 == 0){
    b++;
  }
  else {
    c++;
  }

  sk = sk/10;
}
printf(" Zeros %d \n Evens %d \n Odss %d \n Without Zeros: %d \n Without Odds: %d \n",a , b, c, b+c, a+b);
```

Comment: You should generally explain what you did, not just provide answer with only code.

Comment: Its not working. I need for example if user write 1234 i need that program will write 24 its without odds, and if user write for example 1002 i need that program will write 12  without zeros.

Comment: Your question was: `Number without zeros %d \n Number without odds %d`..., ok i see your change, i will examine..